# How functions get evaluated in Jquery.?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My HTML,

```
<div id="fullcontainer">
    <div id="a">a</div>
    <div id="b">b</div>
    <div id="c">c</div>
</div>
```

JS,

```
   var cache = $('#fullcontainer').children();
   var index = cache.length - 2;
   cache.filter(':lt('+ index +')').remove();
```

The code that i had given above is working fine as expected, since i have cached the length in a separate variable, But the following code without caching is not working,

```
   var cache = $('#fullcontainer').children();
   cache.filter(':lt('+ cache.length - 2 +')').remove();
```

As far as i have learned the expressions at the last level should be evaluated first, But i dont know what is happening with the above piece of codes, Please advice and provide some explanations.

[DEMO of the working one](http://jsfiddle.net/aX83W/2/), [Demo of the non - working one](http://jsfiddle.net/aX83W/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its will work if you enclose `cache.length - 2` in `brackets` like,

```
cache.filter(':lt('+ (cache.length - 2) +')').remove();
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aX83W/4/)

Comment: But i had given a space outside them.? So spaces are not considered in JS.. Am i right.?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy, order of operations says that `':lt(' + cache.length` happens before the `- 2`. Spaces don't change the order, but parenthesis do.

Comment: Agreed with @zzzzBov. Spaces only provide you better readability. Expressions must be enclosed in `brackets` not in `js` but in any language.

Answer (score 2):

Your code `cache.filter(':lt('+ cache.length - 2 +')').remove();` get evaluated to

`cache.filter('NaN)').remove();`

it should be

```
cache.filter(':lt('+ (cache.length - 2) +')').remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap your value in brackets `( )` to make it evaluated as number:

```
cache.filter(':lt('+ (cache.length - 2) +')').remove();
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aX83W/5/)**